Matlab : One step vector affectation to several variables
I wondered if there is a way to affect severals variables as a result of a vector access :
% Matrix of indexes sorted by rows
index_confs = zeros(n_rain, n_slope, n_distance, n_speed);

...
% Filling index_conf with somes values here
...

% Currently i do this 
for i = 1:n_indexes
    indexes = index_confs(i, :);
    
    index_rain = indexes(1);
    index_slope  = indexes(2);
    index_distance = indexes(3);
    index_speed = indexes(4);
end

This is pretty heavy when I have a lot of dimensions, and i wondered why i cannot do this
for i = 1:n_indexes
    [index_rain, index_slope, index_distance, index_speed] = index_confs(i, :);
end

I use Matlab 2021a.
